# Program Runs before accepting second string in input in C

Tags: c, string, gcc

I am trying to run the following code but the program accepts only one string and displays the output immediately without waiting for the second string to be entered. The program is for 2 string concatenation. Here is the code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i, j, len=0;
    char name[100], abc[100];

    printf("\nPlease Enter String 1 =\t");
    scanf("%[^\n]c",&name);
    printf("\nPlease Enter String 2 =\t");
    scanf("%[^\n]c",&abc);

    for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++)
        len++;
    for(j=0; abc[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        len++;
        name[len]=abc[j];
    }

    printf("\nThe Concatenated String Is =\t");
    puts(name);
}
```

Comment: @larsmans - Here is the output from the console window.         blueelvis@Blueelvis:~$ ./a.out

    Please Enter String 1 = Pranav

    Please Enter String 2 = 
    The Concatenated String Is = Pranav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you not to use `scanf`. Better to use `fgets` instead.
By the way the reason that your program accepts only one string and displays the output immediately without waiting for the second string to be entered is the `\n` character left behind by the first `scanf` after pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. To eat up this newline character you may use `gatchar()` after first `scanf`.

```
printf("\nPlease Enter String 1 =\t");
scanf("%[^\n]c",name);
getchar();
printf("\nPlease Enter String 2 =\t");
scanf("%[^\n]c",abc);
```

Other two mistakes are:
1. Wrong increment of `len`

```
for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++)
    len++;
for(j=0; abc[j]!='\0'; j++)
{
    name[len++]=abc[j];  
}
```

2. Reason for weird output is the string is not NUL terminated. Add this line after second for loop.

```
name[len] = '\0'; // add this to null terminate your string.
```

Here is your [working Code](http://ideone.com/nF17jm)

Comment: Thanks for this. It is working now, but I am getting some wierd character after the concatenation of string. Here is the character �
There is one square box with numbers as well in it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; Grrrrr. How I forget that. :D

Comment: @PranavJituri; OK. Problem is solved. See the new update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks dude for solving the query of mine with this much precision :)

Comment: Your welcome. I glad that it helped you. :). In fact this hole credit goes to [Jonathan Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler). Thank to him.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `scanf` instead:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",name);
.....
scanf(" %[^\n]",abc);
```

Please refer to this [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) manual page for more detail of how to use `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets instead of scanf, also you were incrementing len at the wrong place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int len = 0;
    char name[100], abc[100];
    printf("\nPlease Enter String 1 =\t");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    len = strlen(name) - 1;
    name[len] = 0;
    printf("\nPlease Enter String 2 =\t");
    fgets(abc, 100, stdin);
    abc[strlen(abc) - 1] = 0;
    strcpy(name+len, abc);
    printf("\nThe Concatenated String Is =\t");
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to write the LEN in the initialization of For loop? Can't I increment the LEN inside the body of the loop?

Comment: Oops! This is printing some weird output in last.

Comment: @haccks, what do you mean?

Comment: It is working fine [here](http://ideone.com/8uMppL) but giving some weird output in last of the concatenated string on my compiler. Don't know why.

Comment: @haccks - True that, I am also getting some wierd output like Pranav � ��
in the linux environment but only when the string is not getting concatenated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to throw away the newline character ('\n').

Try:

```
while(getchar() != '\n')
    continue;
```

after each `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
printf("\nPlease Enter String 2 =\t");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", abc);
for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++)
    len++;
for(j=0;abc[j]!='\0';j++){
    name[len]=abc[j];
    len++;
}
name[len]='\0';
```

Comment: Bro I am getting only the first string in the output using your syntax. Please Enter String 1 = abc

Please Enter String 2 = abc

The Concatenated String Is = abc

Comment: @PranavJituri Did you confirm the change of position of `len++` ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and yes it is working only when i change the format specifiers inside the scanf function such that the first one accepts input till a newline comes and the second one accepts a "\t" or TAB space. I do not know why this kind of thing is happening?

Comment: Could you please explain? I am new to this C Programming. :)

Comment: "%[^\n]%*c" : `%[^\n]`  it does not require `c`. `%*c` It skip one character(ignore the input corresponding to the `%c`).