# Output Not Right When Calculating A Point About A Circle

Tags: c, math

I am not getting correct output in this program in which I have to calculate whether a point entered is inside the circle or outside the circle or on the boundary of the circle given the centre of the circle and radius of the circle. It is sometimes giving correct answer while other times it is not giving. For example if I enter (0,0) as the centre and put radius = 10 and check the point (10,0) , it says that the point lies outside the circle. Dunno why this is happening as in other cases checked it is giving correct answer. Here is the source code to the program -

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    float x1,y1,x2,y2,r,z;

    printf("Please Enter The X And Y Coordinates Of The Centre Of The Circle = ");

    scanf("%f%f",&x1,&y1);

    printf("\nPlease Enter The Radius Of The Circle = ");

    scanf("%f",&r);

    printf("\nPlease Enter The Coordinates Of The Point You Want To Check");

    scanf("%f%f",&x2,&y2);

    z=x1*x1+x2*x2-2*x1*x2+y1*y1+y2*y2-2*y1*y2;

    if(z*z==r*r)
        printf("\nThe Point Entered Lies On The Boundary Of The Circle Described");

    else if(z*z>r*r)
        printf("\nThe Point Entered Is Outside The Circle Described");

    else
        printf("\nThe Point Entered Lies Inside The Circle");

}
```

Comment: Why not do some debugging, e.g. print the value of `z`?

Comment: Aren't there any `math.h` functions you can use?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey - I know there are functions but going according to the book as I am completing the book now as it was not completed in the semester =.=

Comment: I would suggest you to not to use `main` (I forgot to point it out in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20102277/2455888) . Better use `int main(void)` and add a `return 0;` statement at the end.

Comment: @haccks - I do coding in the Linux environment and hence use the MAIN() directly without writing the VOID. But as you say, the way of writing int main() with return 0 at the end is necessary or it is just a tradition to write it?

Comment: C11 standard: **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**;
`The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
parameters:
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner`.

Comment: @haccks So this is basically done so that the code can be compiled without errors on any compiler?

Comment: This is because it is defined by standard.

Comment: @haccks -Fair Enough. Will keep in mind next time while writing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition

```
 if(z*z==r*r)
```

to

```
 if(z==r*r)
```

and

```
 else if(z*z>r*r)
```

to

```
 else if(z>r*r)
```

because `z` already is the square of the distance between two points you have calculated.

Comment: Thanks dude. Forgot that =.= That's the second time of you helping me. Thanks

Comment: Do you understand where you were doing mistake?

Comment: Yes it was a logical error as it was like compiling [(x1-x2)^2+(y2-y1)^]^2 with Radius^2 which is wrong as far as Maths is concerned.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That was the mistake.

Comment: @haccks Still comparing == some floating point after some math operations won't give you always an equality, although they should, you should use some epsilon here

Comment: @fernando.reyes; And that's because you can't represent every floating point number in binary float precisely, right?

Comment: @fernando.reyes: Using “some epsilon” will cause some results that should have been on the circle (if calculated with exact mathematics) but were inside or outside the circle due to arithmetic errors to again be reported as on the circle. But it also causes some results that that should be reported as inside or outside the circle to be reported as on the circle. Why is it better to reduce the former errors at the expense of increasing the latter errors?

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Agreed. Then what should we do in this case?

Comment: @haccks: In this application? Ignore it. It is a learning exercise; it should not be complicated with material beyond what is being taught. In a real-world application, it would depend on the requirements. In fact, most of the points entered **cannot** lie exactly on the circle, because most of the points on the circle have irrational coordinates and hence cannot be entered in any format `scanf` recognizes.